# How to make a phone call on a button?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to make a button, by clicking on which a mobile number will be called.
The fact is that when compiling to a real device, an error occurs in the console:

```
Error detected during LiveSync on [UUID] for /Users/andrey/Desktop/rentride-apps/rentride-black/rrblack. Error: Unexpected key "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" while parsing <dict/>.
```

This happened after I added the following code, according to the plugin instructions.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>telprompt</string>
</array>
```

What could be the reason?

I use:

- Nativescript-vue
- plugin [nativescript-phone](https://github.com/msywensky/nativescript-phone)
- Client Sidekick
- Real device iPhone

All info.plist

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>
 <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
 <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
 <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
 <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>APPL</string>
 <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>1.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
 <string>????</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1.0</string>
 <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
 <string>LaunchScreen</string>
 <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>armv7</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>
 <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
 <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
 <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>tel</string>
  <string>telprompt</string>
 </array>
 <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire `info.plist` file?

Comment: @Manoj Yes of course. I updated the post.